Kotlin Flows not working as expected when Collecting items in UI Screen using collectAsState(). Also maybe taskDao.insertTask() not working?
`The Task data is not being inserted in database, therefore not collected and rendered in UI.
#TaskViewModel.kt
var taskList: StateFlow<List<Task>> = repository.getAllTasks()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            initialValue = emptyList()
        )

#HomeScreen.kt
val tasks by taskViewModel.taskList.collectAsState()

I was expecting test data to be displayed in UI when the app is run.
#HomeScreen.kt
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(taskViewModel: TaskViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val tasks by taskViewModel.taskList.collectAsState()

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        IconButton(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            onClick = {

                //todo : remove after testing
                (1..10).map { index ->
                    taskViewModel.insertTask(
                        Task(
                            id = index,
                            title = "Task $index",
                            isCompleted = index % 2 == 0,
                            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (index * 2) * 3600000
                        )
                    )
                }
            },

            ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
            )
        }

        //Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color.LightGray)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Tasks:", fontSize = 20.sp
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp, 0.dp)
            ) {
                items(items = tasks, key = { it.id }) {
                    TaskComponent(task = it)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#TaskComponent.kt
@Composable
fun TaskComponent(task: Task, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .padding(start = 10.dp)
            .size(50.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = task.title, fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

#TaskViewModel.kt
@HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TaskRepository) : ViewModel() {

    
    var task: Task by mutableStateOf(
        Task(0, "", false, 0, 0)
    )
        private set
    

    var taskList: StateFlow<List<Task>> = repository.getAllTasks()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            initialValue = emptyList()
        )

    
    fun insertTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insert(task)
        }
    }

    fun updateTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.update(task)
        }
    }

    fun deleteTask(task: Task) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.delete(task)
        }
    }

    fun getTaskById(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getTaskById(id)
        }
    }

    fun getAllTasks() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getAllTasks()
        }
    }

    

}

#Task.kt
@Entity(tableName = "tasks_tbl")
data class Task(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int=0,
    val title: String,
    val isCompleted: Boolean,
    val startTime: Long,
    val endTime: Long
)

#TaskDao.kt
package com.example.crudapp.data

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface TaskDao {
   
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertTask(task: Task) {

    }

    @Update
    suspend fun updateTask(task: Task) {

    }

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTask(task: Task) {

    }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks_tbl WHERE id=:id")
    fun getTaskById(id: Int): Flow<Task>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks_tbl")
    fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<Task>>


}

#TaskDatabase.kt
@Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TaskDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun taskDao(): TaskDao
}

#TaskRepository.kt
class TaskRepository(private val dao: TaskDao) {

    
    suspend fun insert(task: Task) {
        dao.insertTask(task)
    }

    suspend fun update(task: Task) {
        dao.updateTask(task)
    }

    suspend fun delete(task: Task) {
        dao.deleteTask(task)
    }

    fun getTaskById(id: Int): Flow<Task> {
        return dao.getTaskById(id)
    }

    fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<Task>> {
        return dao.getAllTasks()
    }
}

#AppModule.kt
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesLocalDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): TaskDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, TaskDatabase::class.java, "task_db")
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesTaskDao(db: TaskDatabase): TaskDao {
        return db.taskDao()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesTaskRepository(dao: TaskDao): TaskRepository {
        return TaskRepository(dao)
    }

}


In the title of your question you describe a problem with collecting the flow, in the question itself you say that the new data isn't being inserted in the database. So which is it? What exactly is the problem? If it is the latter then please [edit] your question and add the implementation of TaskDao.insertTask so we have the full picture.

Try removing the { } from all your functions in the DAO. You’re supposed to let Room define them. Not sure if giving them an empty default like that might mess it up.

Thank you so much @Tenfour04.
This minor thing took my whole day and I was looking at everything but TaskDao.

Oh, good. I’ll add it as an answer.

Remove the {  } from after the function definitions in the DAO. The brackets are defining an empty (do-nothing) default implementation of the functions, but you want to allow Room to define its own implementation for these functions.
I’m not sure if it’s intended for Room to misbehave when you have default function implementations, but maybe it is designed this way so you can define temporary test functions that behave differently.

First of all, you should rewrite your dao like this:
interface TaskDao {
   
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
    suspend fun insertTask(task: Task)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) 
    suspend fun insertAll(tasks: List<Task>)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateTask(task: Task)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteTask(task: Task)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks_tbl WHERE id=:id")
    fun getTaskById(id: Int): Flow<Task>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks_tbl")
    fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<Task>>
}

then also define a new method insertAll() in your repository:
class TaskRepository(private val dao: TaskDao) {

    
    suspend fun insert(task: Task) {
        dao.insertTask(task)
    }
    suspend fun insertAll(tasks: List<Task>) {
        dao.insertAll(tasks)
    }

    suspend fun update(task: Task) {
        dao.updateTask(task)
    }

    suspend fun delete(task: Task) {
        dao.deleteTask(task)
    }

    fun getTaskById(id: Int): Flow<Task> {
        return dao.getTaskById(id)
    }

    fun getAllTasks(): Flow<List<Task>> {
        return dao.getAllTasks()
    }
}


then inside your ViewModel define the following new method:
@HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: TaskRepository) : ViewModel() {
   
   // rest of the code...
   
   fun insertTasks(tasks: List<Task>) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertAll(tasks)
        }
    }
}

This way you can do a bulk insertion to add your test data.
IconButton(
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            onClick = {
                //todo : remove after testing
                val newTasks = (1..10).map { index ->
                    Task(
                        id = index,
                        title = "Task $index",
                        isCompleted = index % 2 == 0,
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (index * 2) * 3600000
                    )
                }
                taskViewModel.insertTasks(newTasks)
            },

            ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
            )
        }


Can you please add some explanation why this solves the problem? Also, the new MutableList was a bit confusing so I took the liberty and simplified it a bit.

Thank you Leviathan for removing that extra declaration of mutable list. I appreciate it. I have removed the default implementation for the dao methods so the room can decide on their implementation. More ever it shows a bulk insertion of the test data rather than we insert tasks one by one.
